# Iterator not allowing in reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am trying to cod the following in my reducer and a compilation error is turning up as follows:

> The method `collect(Text, Text)` in the type `OutputCollector<Text,Text>` is not applicable for the arguments `(Text, Iterator<Text>)`

```
public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {            
   output.collect(key, values);
}
```

As far as I know, the output of `map <K,V>` are shuffled and sorted which forms a collection for the reducer input.

Can I know the reason behind the error ?

Comment: I guess that the error message quite says it all... `The method collect(Text, Text) in the type OutputCollector<Text,Text> is not applicable for the arguments (Text, Iterator<Text>)`, which means that `values` is an `Iterator<Text>`, when it should be a `Text`

Answer (score 4):

The problem the error message is calling out is that type signatures of the `OutputCollector<K,V>` class  and the `collect(K,V)` method have to match.

In this case they don't match because you declared

```
OutputCollector<Text, Text> output
```

but tried to call

```
output.collect(key, values);
```

with the type of `values` being `Iterator<Text>`, which doesn't match the value type Text for the value expected by your `OutputCollector<Text,Text>`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the error, as [paisanco states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37336443/2516301) is that `values` is an iterator, when you have declared through `OutputCollector<Text, Text>` that the output key will be of type `Text` and the output value will also be of type `Text`.

In order to solve this problem, you can:

- set the IdentityReducer as your reducer (for this specific problem), by calling 
  `setReducerClass(IdentityReducer.class);` in your Driver, or by not stating any reducer class (the IdentityReducer is the default reducer).
- change the reduce method as:

  ```
  public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
     for (Text value: values) {            
         output.collect(key, value); //value is of type Text
     }
  }
  ```

  , which is nothing more than the implementation of an identity reducer.

Comment: So how would it change with the implementation of IdentityReducer ?

Comment: @Sri how would what change? Identity reducer is not what you have. It is what I describe in the second bullet. The two bullets that I describe as alternatives are equivalent, if that's what you are asking.